# How to display pictures on multiple rows , android

Tags: android

i want to have a gallery that has multiple rows (the pictures are from web so the number is dynamic) 
I tried to use gallery but they appear in centre and all in same row, I don t know what atributes regard this functionality

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use GridView instead? http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html